# Let $K\subseteq X$ be a convex set. Then $K$ is normed closed if and only if $w$-closed (i.e., closed in the weak topology).

Tags: functional-analysis

> **Corollary 1**: Let $K$ be a closed convex set in a Banach space $X$ and let $x_0\notin K$. Then, there exists $f\in X^*$ such that $f(x_0)>\sup_{x\in K}f(x)$.

The author applies corollary 1 is the proof of the following corollary:

> **Corollary 2**: Let $K\subseteq X$ be a convex set. Then $K$ is normed closed if and only if $w$-closed (i.e., closed in the weak topology).
>
> *Proof*. Let $K$ be a $w$-closed set and let $x_n\to x$ in norm, $x_n\in K$. For any $f\in X^*$ we have that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ and hence $x\in K$. Thus $K$ is closed in norm.
>
> Assume that $K$ is norm closed. Let us prove that
> $$
> K=\bigcap_{H_f(a)\supseteq K}H_f(a),
> $$
> where $H_f(a):=\{x:a\leq f(x)\}$. It is clear that if $x\in K$, then $x$ belongs to the right hand part of the equality. If $x\notin K$, then by corollary 1 there exists $f_0\in X^*$ such that
> $f_0(x)<a\leq f_0(K)$, i.e., $K\subseteq H_{f_0}(a)$ but $x\notin H_{f_0}(a)$. Thus $K$ is the intersection of $w$-closed sets and therefore $K$ is $w$-closed.

What I don't understand in this proof is why "if $x\notin K$, then by corollary 1 there exists $f_0\in X^*$ such that $f_0(x)<a\leq f_0(K)$". If this could be explained, I'll understand the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Corollary 1 (taking $x_0=x$) there exists $f \in X^{*}$ such that $$f(x_0) >\sup_{x \in K} f(x).$$ Let $$b \in (\sup_{x \in K} f(x), f(x_0))$$ Let $f_0=-f$ and $a =-b$. Then $$f_0(x_0) <a<-\sup_{x \in K} f_0(x)=\inf_{x \in K}  f_0(x)$$

(so $f_0(x_0) <a< f_0(x)$ for all $x \in K$).

Comment: One minor comment: did you mean $b\in\left(\sup_{x\in K}f(x),f(x_0)\right)$?

Comment: @D.Math Yes, thanks for pointing out.